# Understanding this python code

Tags: python-2.7

This code was on an exam and it asked what it's output was going to be.

I got it wrong unfortunately and put it was all 1's.

I'm a little confused with what this program is doing specifically with the if/else statement.

I'm a C programmer, so if possible could someone please translate the if/else statement into C code so I can understand what is going on. Thank you!

EDIT: to clarify, I'm not sure what the condition means "if x in d"

```
def somefunction(L):
    d = {}

    for x in L:
        if x in d:
            d[x] = d[x] + 1

        else:
            d[x] = 1

    return d

L = [6, 10, -2, 2, 6, 4, -2, 6]
print somefunction(L)


output: {10: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1, -2: 2, 6: 3}
```

Comment: It counts the number of times each value appears in `L`. `if x in d` means "if there is an element in the dictionary d which key is x, then..."

Comment: One nice thing about Python, or perhaps one not-nice things about C, is that a simple thing like `d[x] = d[x] + 1` or `x in d` requires thousands of lines of library code to accurately translate into C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`in` in Python performs a containment check. It looks at the right-hand operand to see if it contains the left-hand operand.

```
>>> 2 in [1, 2, 4]
True
>>> 3 in [1, 2, 4]
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd encourage you NOT to translate everything into C. Python is considerably different and trying to keep things in a C frame of mind will make things harder to understand.

One thing that is great is that Python is interpreted, so you can type "python" and then enter commands to see what they do. You can exam all the variables as things are manipulated. For example, you can do:

```
L = [6, 10, -2, 2, 6, 4, -2, 6]
for x in L:
    print x
```

To see what the "in" does. Likewise for the rest of the code.  Also, there are great online tutorials on Python, Google "Dive into Python", for example.

Answer (score 0):

See Basically in this code what you are doing is you are making a count of no of times the element is repeated in the list..you are using dictionary as a means to take the count..

First of all in the if-else block you are checking whether the element is present or not..if its present then you are incrementing the count using the element as key..else you are creating a new key,key being the element and default value being 1...

Thus you iterate all over the list and check the count of each element in the list..

```
d[i]=j
#i is key,j is value.
```

And at last you print your findings by printing the dictionary..!!